# Randomly getting logged out on Ubuntu-Gnome 15.10

Tags: 15.10, ubuntu-gnome

I am randomly getting logged out on Ubuntu-Gnome 15.10, while in mid of some work. It takes me back to login screen. It mostly happens when I am using Chrome browser, but I am not sure on whether there is any causality there.

It used to work fine when using Ubuntu-Gnome 15.04 and 14.04.

Also this is a clean install of Ubuntu-Gnome, and all packages and kernel are updated.

I am losing a lot of work in between.

Answer (score 0):

The same happens to me with Gnome 3.14.1 in debian stable (jessie).

If it's useful, it happens in a HP ProBook 4G with an "VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)"

It happens both in "gnome classic" and in "gnome" modes.